# Shared Code Layout

Tags: c++, visual-studio, solution, projects

I have two C++ projects in a solution both of which need to share two common classes. What I want to avoid is having two copies of the source files but I am reluctant to just include the source in one project and reference it in the other.

How is this sort of situation normally handled?

Comment: Why are you reluctant to include the source in one and reference it from the other?

Comment: Can you please clarify with some context about the responsibilities of the shared classes and the projects that use them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a third project, which is either a dynamic or static library (prefer the latter for ease of use) and put the shared code in there. The two other projects #include the headers from the library project and link with library project binary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you point me to any code examples or articles so I can get to grips with this?

Comment: What development environment are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 for Win32.